# HTTPS, SSL or TLS Issue with Browsers on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, firefox, ssl, opera

I don't know what I did yesterday, something went wrong with my browsers.

All my browsers takes forever to load

`Chrome` shows `establishing secure connection...`

`Firefox` shows `Performing TLS handshake with <website>...`

`Opera` is trying to redirect somewhere like `redir.opera...`

Can't browse anything.

I have tried to configure internet option, proxy settings, turn off 'Automatic discover' on LAN settings etc (as suggested on other threads) but no use.

Haven't encountered something like this before.

I am suspecting something changed on OS itself which browsers are trying to use that settings.

I am using Windows 10.

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After googling for sometime, I came up with this to solve the issue.

```
1. Run command prompt or PowerShell as administrator
2. then run this command
   > netsh int ip reset
3. Restart the computer.
```

For me everything went back to normal and working.

Hope this might help someone with similar problem.